# What sound formats does Sifteo support?

Tags: cubes, sifteo

I'm trying to play some sounds on my cubes but no luck
I have a cheers.wav in my /assets/sounds
and i'm calling it like this:

```
Sound cheers = Sounds.CreateSound("cheers");
cheers.Play(1,0);
```

changing the name throws an exception in the CreateSound() Method, so I know its loading it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are wav and mp3, although some wav's did not work for me, mp3 works fine